# is_unique codeigniter is it syncronized?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is is_unique in form_validation of codeigniter synchronized? If two concurrent requests check for a email and both gets false, will both write the value to the database or how is it synchronized? (if the column is not set as unique)

Comment: If you're worried about this sort of race condition, use a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

This is (essentially) the `is_unique` function:

```
return $this->CI->db->limit(1)->get_where($table, array($field => $str))->num_rows() === 0
```

As you can see it is a simple `get_where`. If `num_rows` is 0 then the function returns true as in the value is unique.

That being said, I highly doubt your website will get so much traffic that requests happen at the same time, even so, any function that you could write would basically be the same as `form_validation`s implementation.

Now depending on the *type* of query you could probably mitigate any potential issues with a transaction. Unfortunately, CodeIgniter doesn't have any cool locking functions that Laravel or other more modern frameworks have.